# Update Google chart with data received from server

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I make a chart change with new data? I get data back from an API call to my server, which I can see in the console. How do I update the chart with it?

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    var hdms = ol.proj.transform(
        coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
        $.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/stats?lat="+hdms[1]+"&lon="+hdms[0], 
        function(data) {
             console.log( data );
        });
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) load google first

`google.charts.load` can replace --> `$(document).ready` (or similar)

2) create chart
3) get data

something like...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
    // save reference to chart here
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        var hdms = ol.proj.transform(
            coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
            $.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/stats?lat="+hdms[1]+"&lon="+hdms[0],
            function(data) {
                console.log( data );
                // draw chart here
                chart.draw(data);
            });
        );
    };
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

you must create a [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#datatable-class) to draw the chart

there are a few ways to create the data table

1) you can use JSON, but it must be in the following format, as [found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

```
var jsonData = {
  cols: [
    {label: 'x', type: 'number'},
    {label: 'y', type: 'number'}
  ],
  rows: [
    {c:[{v: 0}, {v: 0}]},
    {c:[{v: 1}, {v: 1}]}
  ]
}
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

2) you can use simple array data, and static method `arrayToDataTable`

```
var arrayData = [
  ['x', 'y'],
  [0, 0],
  [1, 1]
];
var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
```

3) or manually add columns and rows

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'x');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'y');
dataTable.addRow([0, 0]);

// -- or addRows --

dataTable.addRows([
  [0, 0],
  [1, 1]
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for fast response. I implemented your code and getting this error  "You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView". I will try to solve this, have general idea but if you have experience I would appriciate any help.

Comment: see __UPDATE__ above, wasn't sure what type of data you are using -- you may need to transform to one of the formats above -- if you can share a sample, i can help...